# Make separate mail server from web server

Tags: dns

We have one physical server: there are www (web site) and mail on it. 
Server has 2 public ip addresses, one for www and one for mail. 
Server also has DNS on it, O/S is Red Hat Linux. 
We want to make mail separate from www. 
For www it is no problem, it stays on that server and DNS will work.

If we move mail to other server:

1. Should we install DNS on mail server too? Or is it just enough to show A record and MX record for mail on www server?
2. How to point www's DNS in mail server? Is it OK if we point www's DNS in `NAMESERVERS` parameter?
3. As I understand, DNS in www server will work both for www server and mail server, and in mail server we can stop `named` service. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a good idea to physically separate both web server and mail server. You have lot of control and easy for upgrades and maintenance.

> Should we install DNS on mail server too? Or is it just enough to show
>   A record and MX record for mail on www server?

It is just enough to point the A & MX record in the DNS server (Webserver)

> How to point www's DNS in mail server? Is it OK if we point www's DNS
>   in NAMESERVERS parameter?

Yes, you can add webserver's IP as the DNS in the Mail server. That would absolutely work.

> As I understand, DNS in www server will work both for www server and
>   mail server, and in mail server we can stop named service. Am I right?

Yes, all you need is a single mail server and you can add the mail server to that webservers's DNS.

Comment: everything is clear and easy now. Thank you very much!

Comment: A small note: you never needed the DNS to run on the same server. You never needed two IP addresses.

Comment: Yes, @itdev you can configure what ctrl-alt-delor mentioned.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, why don't I need 2 ip addresses? I did not understand

Comment: Web server works on port 80 and Mail server don't use that port and which is why you can have single IP address for both web and mail.

Comment: Services sit on a socket (a ip-address/port tuple). Mail and web use different ports.

Comment: @RubanSavvy, but I cant have one ip on both physical separate servers

Comment: It's important to note that Reverse DNS should be setup properly if one is running an email server.  If rDNS is not setup properly, sent email may very well get placed in a user's spam mail or rejected outright by receiving servers.

Comment: @RubberStamp, it can be configured on same web server (www) dns, can't it?